# get the text in a UIView？

Tags: ios, uiview

I draw text in a UIView

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
 [tempPageStr drawAtPoint:tempDrawPoint withFont:pagefont];
}
```

I want to implenment the select effect of some Text in the UIView like textView,webView with my code.

I think too much ,no any ideal.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean an interactive selection ?

Comment: yes,I want to use the selected Text.

Comment: you can use uneditable textview for this , it will be the same as you want

Answer (score 0):

the textView  can't modify the backgroundColor of menu，so I think this method。